# Pod trunk delete in Cocoapods and version number re-use

Tags: cocoapods

Cocoapods has the `pod trunk delete` command. I haven't used Cocoapods before so I want to use this command to push a prototype of our pod spec and then delete it. Our hosting isn't finalized so the spec won't be pointing to the final hosting location of our library. But I wasn't sure exactly the scope of this:

> Deletes the specified pod version from trunk and the master specs
> repo. Once deleted, this version can never be pushed again.

If I delete something like 1.0-beta1, does just beta1 become ineligible for another push? Or does the entire 1.0 release become ineligible?

Comment: If you're planning to delete from the start, you should almost certainly use a private deployment. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: Our interest is in how our pod is presented on the Cocoapods sites. How all the metadata is presented, etc. We have a private deployment we've already tested. But what we're looking at is a one time only deployment we can go through to test out our automation and our podspec's presentation without making a mistake that ends up being permanent.